# Do I need to wire a CAT5e cable a certain way to provide digital TV over fiber optic?

Tags: home-networking, tv, voip, wired-networking, iptv

Fiber optic internet, phone, and TV service comes in to an outside mounted ONT. Two CAT5E cables run into the home from 2 of the 6 ports on the the ONT, which I am assuming is one for internet and one for TV.

The cables run into a basement networking closet along with the cables from each wall-jack in each room of the house which I have already wired with punchdown keystones and RJ45 connectors.

The CAT5e cable that provides internet from the ONT is connected to a router and the router connected to a 24-port switch.  The other CAT5e cable from the ONT (that I assume provides the TV) is plugged into the switch.

I have no internet on any of the wall jacks and no TV. I have wireless internet from the router, but nothing hard wired. I am wondering if there is some special way I need to be wiring my CAT5e ethernet cables. I wired on the RJ45's to the "A" standard as well as the keystones in the walls of each room. Right now, I am more concerned with getting the TV working, as I currently have internet as WiFi.

Does TV over IP need a specific CAT5e wiring? I really don't know where to start. I sort of took on a job that once I got started, quickly became more than I bargained for. I haven't yet checked the RJ45's on the ONT end to see if they are wired for "A" or "B", but could that even be the problem?

Switch is a NETGEAR JGS524NA and the router is a LINKSYS AC4000.

Comment: "The other CAT5e cable from the ONT (that I assume provides the TV) is plugged into the switch." - Switch distributes one signal to multiple destinations, it can't manage multiple inputs. Also TV signal maybe different protocol so your switch can't manage it. Maybe hire a professional...

Answer (score 0):

First something that seems a bit... worrying:

> The CAT5e cable that provides internet from the ONT is connected to a router and the router connected to a 24-port switch. The other CAT5e cable from the ONT (that I assume provides the TV) is plugged into the switch.

If the ISP provides separate ports for "Internet" and "IPTV", that implies they're on separate networks. (And connecting your own router creates a yet another network – your LAN. But that does not change the situation.)

Simply connecting both networks to the same Ethernet switch bridges them together and can have various unpleasant results. Accidental network loops are not unheard of.

More commonly, if both networks use DHCP, then it's purely down to random chance which device picks up which network's lease offer first. Maybe your computer keeps joining the IPTV network, and your TV keeps joining the regular LAN, so neither can access what they want.

It is certainly possible to carry separate networks over a single Ethernet cable, but your switches must support **VLAN tagging** (aka 802.1Q). For example, configure the basement switch to accept port 1 (Internet) as VLAN 1; port 2 (IPTV) as VLAN 2; and output *tagged* VLANs on port 3. (Yes, this would need more expensive "smart" or "managed" switches.)

---

Back to wiring:

The ONT converts between some form of fiber networking and regular Ethernet. So the cables should match the standard Ethernet wiring (TIA/EIA-568), but nothing really special besides that.

IP (the network layer) does not care about the physical connections. As long as the layer below (Ethernet) does its job, then IP should work fine. Do the "link" lights on your Ethernet switches at least light up?

Ethernet (the data-link layer) won't know the difference between 568A and 568B, as long as both ends of the cable are the same. But make sure you didn't accidentally *split* a pair – it would severely degrade the link quality. (The middle pins are paired 3-6, 4-5, and *not* 3-4, 5-6.) If in doubt, test with a pre-made cable.

It could also be that the wiring between your jacks in the walls is bad, or that it simply goes to a different room than you're thinking.

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out, there was a reason that there was no TV or internet from any of the wall jacks. Further up the lines in the ceiling, it looks as though someone had tried splicing multiple CAT5E cables together to create one long cable for TV. I am assuming they were trying to get their TV to a room that already had cable ran to it, but it just didn't connect back to the ONT in any way. They figured they'd make a path from the ONT to that room by splicing the various cables involved together with butt connectors. Problem is, they did it wrong they somehow were spicing together the wrong individual wires.

So, to troubleshoot the problem to see if I was right, I cut off all their butt connectors and quickly wired on a punchdown keystone in their place and a RJ45 on the other cable that needed to be spliced to it and simply plugged them in together. After making the final connection and rebooting the ONT, TV came back up in the room and the weird part - so did the internet on the wall jacks (minus 3 that I had to go back and replace the RJ45 due to a bad crimp on them).

Because the home was already finished and I don't know of any way to pull a continuous CAT5E in a zig-zag pattern through multiple floors and walls to the ONT, I asked the homeowner if they were ok with it and they said yes.

Am I overlooking some glaring problem by leaving things wired this way? I know it's not ideal and it's not "right", but I worked with what I had from a previous attempt someone made and did the best I could. Should this setup be fine?